# How should I remove static datatype warning

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhCEe.png)

How should I remove static datatype warning in my project.

Static datatype is necessary in my project, how should I can fix this warning without deleting code

Comment: Hi Aniket Jain, I have two things for your problem click on the yellow lightbulb. That will show tips on what to do/what IntelliJ recommends. And two please next time post your code instead, because image will eventually be removed, so whenever someone else has the same problem they can't see the image anymore.

Comment: Don't use static views and layouts... That's why you're getting this warning... Memery leak warning you can't resolve

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think static members are necessary for your case so someone could suggest an alternate approach that doesn't leak memory. That would certainly be better than just suppressing the warnings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should never use static **Context**, **View** or **ViewGroup** elements in your app, since it may generate memory leaks.

Comment: so what should i use to remove my warning.

Comment: You can add @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") above DesignerToast class.

Comment: Your answer is a comment and your comment is the answer. You could also provide an example with what you said in the answer to make it an actual answer.